# do content added to DOM count for the total page load time?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onload

I mean if I append some contents like this:

```
<body>
 //contents
 <script>body.appendChild('<img src="new.png">');
 // other contents
</body>
```

the browser will fire window.onload considering only the original html or it will take in consideration the load of the new image too? (`new.png`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that code/markup being incorrect, it *will* consider the new image. To append it to the DOM will be to download whatever the `src` attribute points to.

However, if this code was placed inside of a `window.onload = function() { ... }`, then it wouldn't be considered because its download would not occur until your window was loaded.

Here is the code that would actually work...

```
var img = new Image;

img.src = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3535689c965d66db3d2a936ced96192a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG';
img.alt = 'Example';

document.body.appendChild(img);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Us7qE/).

Comment: `Besides that code/markup being incorrect, it will consider the new image` are you sure?

Comment: @yes123 Check out the new fiddle, the load of the image is always being fired before window load. This is with the JavaScript being inserted in the `body` element.

Comment: tested that's right. At this point i don't get why google analytics code claims it will not interfere with the page load time if their appendChild will anyway count for the window.onload

Comment: @yes123 If they wait until all images have downloaded first, and then add their image it should be OK I think.